Shade region defined by line
I am currently producing this plot:

Via the following code:
Sites = {{4,-0.5,1.5}, {4.5,0,1.5},{3.5,0,1.5},{4,0.5,1.5},{4.5,0.5,2}, {3.5,0.5,2}, {4,0,2}, {4,0.5,2.5},{3.5,0,2.5},{4,-0.5,2.5},{4.5,0,2.5},{3.5,-0.5,2},{4.5,-0.5,2}}
Points=ListPointPlot3D[Sites, PlotStyle->PointSize[0.06]]

plane1 =Graphics3D[{Thickness[0.005],Line[{{4.5,0,1.5},{4,0.5,1.5},{4.5,0.5,2},{4.5,0,1.5}}]}]
plane2 =Graphics3D[{Thickness[0.005],Line[{{4,-0.5,1.5},{3.5,0,1.5},{3.5,0.5,2},{4,0.5,2.5},{4.5,0,2.5},{4.5,-0.5,2},{4,-0.5,1.5}}]}]
plane3 =Graphics3D[{Thickness[0.005],Line[{{4,-0.5,2.5},{3.5,0,2.5},{3.5,-0.5,2},{4,-0.5,2.5}}]}]

Show[Points,plane1,plane2,plane3]

From here I would like the planes defined by two triangles and the hexagon to be coloured.
What is the best way to acchive that?

Have you tried using Polygon instead of Line?

@Domen I did not know that was a function. That seams like the perfect solution. Thank you!

$Version

"14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)"

Clear["Global`*"]

As Domen pointed out, Polygon is the solution; however, your code can be simplified by defining sites partitioned as used by the polygons.
sites = {{{4.5, 0, 1.5}, {4, 0.5, 1.5}, {4.5, 0.5, 2}, {4.5, 0, 
     1.5}}, {{4, -0.5, 1.5}, {3.5, 0, 1.5}, {3.5, 0.5, 2}, {4, 0.5, 
     2.5}, {4.5, 0, 2.5}, {4.5, -0.5, 2}, {4, -0.5, 1.5}}, {{4, -0.5, 
     2.5}, {3.5, 0, 2.5}, {3.5, -0.5, 2}, {4, -0.5, 2.5}}};

Graphics3D[{
  Opacity[0.3, Blue], EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], Polygon[sites],
  Opacity[1, Blue], PointSize[0.06], Point /@ Flatten[sites, 1]}]



MeshRegion
reg = MeshRegion[
   Sites, {Polygon[{2, 4, 5}], Polygon[{10, 9, 12}], 
    Polygon[{1, 3, 6, 8, 11, 13}]}];
HighlightMesh[reg, {Style[0, Red], Style[1, Cyan], 
  Style[2, {Opacity[.2], Blue}]}]


